# JQUERY DataTables - Keep Table stying on print

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am trying different ways to keep the table styling when I print a data table. I am well aware that data tables currently strips all table styling except the main table class. I have began trying a few different things and modifying the buttons.print.js file in order to achieve this.

```
var a = c.buttons.exportData(d.exportOptions),
                k = function (b, a) {
                    for (var c = '<tr class="' + (this).className + '">', d = 0, e = b.length; d < e; d++) c += "<" + a + ">" + b[d] + "</" + a + ">";
                    return c + "</tr>"
                },
```

This returns as undefined for the classes...has anyone had any luck out there...or have any tips or examples of what I am trying to achieve?

Also here is the link for the complete buttons.print.js file that I am working with: [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/khemikal/f422q3nu/)

Answer (score 0):

Myself and my colleague figured this out for anyone that would like to retain classes/styling for the tables when they are trying to print...

```
var a = c.buttons.exportData(d.exportOptions),
      counter = [];
      k = function (b, a) {
          if(a != 'th') {
              counter.push(a);
          }                   
          for (var c = "<tr class=" + $('tr:nth-child(' + counter.length + ')').attr('class') + ">", d = 0, e = b.length; d < e; d++) c += "<" + a + ">" + b[d] + "</" + a + ">";
          return c + "</tr>"
      },
```

One thing to note is that this will only work correctly if one data table is on the screen...still working out a way to support multiple tables correctly...